# Countdown clock methods

Tags: java, android

I have a `CountDownTimer` in my app setup like this:

```
new CountDownTimer(11000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        clock.setText("Seconds Remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        secsrem = (int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         //...}
  }.start();
```

I need to access the `onFinish` method in another method in my app so that when a button is pressed it will call the timers `onFinish` method. How would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store your timer in a variable:

```
public class YourClass {

public CountDownTimer timer = null;

...
timer = new CountDownTimer(11000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            clock.setText("Seconds Remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            secsrem = (int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             //...}
      }

timer.start();
...
```

Then you can do:

```
timer.onFinish();
```

Btw, I think you should not call `onFinish` yourself, it will be called by system when the time is up. If you want to cancel the timer instead use:

```
timer.cancel();
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error, I've stored the timer in a variable as shown but when i try and call timer.onFinish(); it says that it cannot be resolved.

Comment: I'll explain a bit more, i have an app which is showing maths expressions, the user has 10 seconds to answer the question. When they press the # key their answer is checked and it displays the next question, however if the user runs out of time then it moves onto the next question.

Comment: Make sure `timer` variable is accessible from where you call it. See my edited answer.